# How to feed ghostscript DLL library to python in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, ghostscript, python-3.9

Background. I'd like to use [`camelot.read_pdf(file)`](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/extract-pdf-tables-in-python-camelot) which uses ghostscript.

1. The project has `ghostscript` package.
2. Windows 10 got installed [Ghostscript 9.54.0 for Windows (64 bit)](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html).
   2.1. `c:\Program Files\gs\gs9.54.0\bin` has been added to system `PATH` env variable.
3. Python 3.9 64 bit.

The required library path is `c:\Program Files\gs\gs9.54.0\bin\gsdll64.dll`.
But python does not “see” it. As it's, probably, not loaded in the system.

```
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\.virtualenvs\PROJECT\lib\site-packages\camelot\backends\ghostscript_backend.py", line 31, in convert
    raise OSError(
OSError: Ghostscript is not installed. You can install it using the instructions here: https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/install-deps.html
```

So, how it should work? Which step did I miss?

Comment: Is your `PATH` environmetn variable correct? It should contain `c:\Program Files\gs\gs9.54.0\bin` - in order to find the `gsdll64.dll` within the python interpreter.

Comment: @Petesh, yes, I've added `c:\Program Files\gs\gs9.54.0\bin` to `PATH`.

Comment: @Petesh, thanks for this note, just double-checked how it's actually presented in Python. And it wasn't, PyCharm had to be restarted. Now it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

First, Python can find DLL by paths from environment PATH variable. So, the path `c:\Program Files\gs\gs9.54.0\bin` has to be presented there.

PyCharm (or another IDE) has to be reloaded (that's my main mistake).

Thanks @Petesh to the comment.